# Angular Subcribe - Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'ToDo[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more

Tags: angular, http, https, subscribe

The code returns the error Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'ToDo[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

This is usually caused by the return observable not being set as an array. In my case the return type is an array but this error keeps breaking my app. Despite working previously.

```php
toDoList: ToDo[];   
this.usertodo = this.getUserTodo(this._userId);

getUserTodo(id: number): ToDo[] {
    return this.DataService.apiGetUserTodo(id).subscribe(
        todo => {
            this.toDoList = todo;
        }
    );
}
```

// IN DATA SERVICE

```php
apiGetUserTodo(id: number): Observable<ToDo[]> {
    const url = `${this.APIurl}/users/${id}/todos`;
    return this.http.get<ToDo[]>(url).pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('USER ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
    );
}
```

This should be error free however this message comes up

> ERROR in src/app/todo/todo.component.ts:28:8 - error TS2740: Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'ToDo[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

Answer (score 2):

That's because your method `getUserTodo()` returns a `Subscription` not a `ToDo[]`.
I think you don't need the `usertodo` at all. You can call the `getUserTodo()` in the `ngOnInit()` for example and the rest is ok. `toDoList` will be filled when you call `getUserTodo()`.

Or you can change the return type of the `getUserTodo()` to `Subscription`.

Comment: I get what you're are saying. I'm using this as a filter based on the user. Would the way around for me would be to clear the toDoList and fill it with user specific ToDo objects? I've been moving it from an in memory api to a .net core one

Comment: I think you don't need to do that. When you want to get new data for another user you just call `getUserTodo(id)` and it will update `toDoList`. If I understand your question correctly.

Comment: NOT @igor_c, The error comes because Ktall equal a variable of type "any" to a variable of type Todo[]. you can avoid the error simply write `.subscribe((todo:Todo[]) => { this.toDoList = todo; })` or `.subscribe((todo:any[]) => { this.toDoList = todo as Todo[]; })`

Comment: I don't think that this is happening, as Typescript can infer the type. As `apiGetUserTodo()` returns an Observable of `ToDo[]` the `todo` type in the subscribe is correct, not any.

Answer (score 1):

```
Please try using below code 

export class ToDo {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    complete: boolean;
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getUserTodo(1);
}

// please add void return type instead of ToDo[], because you have already subscribe in the below method

getUserTodo(id: number) {
    this.DataService.apiGetUserTodo(id).subscribe(todo => {
      this.toDoList = todo;
      this.usertodo = todo;
   });
}


    apiGetUserTodo(id: number): Observable<ToDo[]> {
        const url = `api/users/${id}/todos`;
        return this.http.get<ToDo[]>(url)
        .pipe(
            map(data => {
                console.log('USER ' + JSON.stringify(data));
                return data;
            })
        );
    }
```

Comment: In that case you should remove `return` from the method. But it won't work as you're assigning to the property `usertodo` the result of the method which returns nothing

Comment: @igor_c are you able to help with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68169715/mat-autocomplete-error-when-using-formarray)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason - The code works as expected despite the error being present. The array is filled with ToDo objects.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an any variable to catch the subscription then assign the sliced variable to your class variable.

```
toDoList: ToDo[];
toDo: any;

this.usertodo = this.getUserTodo(this._userId);

getUserTodo(id: number): ToDo[] {
    return this.DataService.apiGetUserTodo(id).subscribe(
        todo => {
            this.toDo = todo;
            this.toDoList = this.toDo.slice();
        }
    );
}
```